# getting values from table when checkbox is checked php

Tags: php, html

I have this code to show my table:

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
   <table cellspacing='0'>
 <?php      
    if(isset($_GET["ordem"])){

    if($_GET["ordem"] == 'descendente'){
        echo "<thead><tr><th><a title='Ordenar por título' href='visualizarVoucher.php'>Utilizador</a></th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<th>Voucher</th>";
        echo "<th>Categoria</th>";
        echo "<th>Preço</th>";
        echo "<th>Confirmação</th>";
        echo "<th>Enviar mail</th>";
        echo "</tr></thead>";
    }
    elseif($_GET["ordem"] == 'ascendente'){
            echo "<thead><tr><th><a title='Ordenar por título' href='visualizarVoucher.php?ordem=descendente'>Utilizador</a></th>";
            echo "<th>Email</th>";
            echo "<th>Voucher</th>";
            echo "<th>Categoria</th>";
            echo "<th>Preço</th>";
            echo "<th>Confirmação </th>";
            echo "<th>Enviar mail</th>";
        echo ("</tr></thead>");
    }                       
}
else{
    echo "<thead><tr><th><a title='Ordenar por título' href='visualizarVoucher.php?ordem=ascendente'>Utilizador</a></th>";
    echo "<th>Email</th>";
    echo "<th>Voucher</th>";
    echo "<th>Categoria</th>";
    echo "<th>Preço</th>";
    echo "<th>Confirmação</th>";
    echo "<th>Enviar mail</th>";
    echo("</tr></thead>");
}              


    while($stmt->fetch()){
            echo("<tbody>");
            echo("<tr><td>$nomeUser</td>");
            echo("<td>$email</td>");
            echo("<td>$nomeVoucher</td>");
            echo("<td>$categoria</td>");
            echo("<td>$preco</td>");
            echo("<td>$confirmacao</td>");
            $content = file_get_contents($file,$filePDF);
            echo("<td><INPUT TYPE='checkbox' NAME='mail[]' multiple='yes'></td>");
            echo("</tr>");
            echo("</tbody>");
    }$stmt->close();     ?>
```

I have a checkbox in my table and I would like to know how can I get the values of each rows from the table when i selected the checkbox. I want to send email when the user selected multiple checkbox.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the code above is a snippet of a larger page, but if not:

- You aren't actually wrapping your input elements in an HTML `form` tag. Doing so will cause the user agent (presumably a browser) to treat each input tag as something to be submitted to your backend form.
- You should wrap the tables in a `table` element; `tbody` is a child of a table.

Regardless of the above:

- It looks like your PHP code above will render the entire `tbody` each time the statement fetches a new row, which is a bit weird. I'd assume you only want to render a row containing mail options?
- To the best of my knowledge, there is no `multiple` attribute allowed in a `checkbox` element. You may be thinking of the `select` element.
- You are not setting a `value` attribute on your checkbox `input` tag. If the user actually submits a form, you'll either get a set of empty `mail[]` variables, or nothing at all, I'm not actually sure which.

Consider the code below: Note that the checkboxes have the same `name` attribute, but different values.

```
<form method="post">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mail[]" value="val1" id="mail-val1" />
                    <label for="mail-val1">Value 1</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mail[]" value="val2" id="mail-val2" />
                    <label for="mail-val2">Value 2</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mail[]" value="val3" id="mail-val3" />
                    <label for="mail-val3">Value 3</label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Given this form, if the user selects all three of the checkboxes and submits, your server will receive a POST request with the payload:

```
mail[]=val1&mail[]=val2&mail[]=val3
```

Depending on how PHP parses that response (it's been about a decade since I've dealt with PHP), you'll probably have an array variable accessible to your application:

```
# mail == ["val1", "val2", "val3" ]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry Palpatim...I didn´t post all my entire code...I have edit again my code...Look my post again please

Comment: Well, you didn't really do anything to address my comments, so I don't have too much to add. In addition, you haven't closed the form, or added a submit element to actually let a user send the data to your server-side script. Do some work to clean up the code based on what I've already said, then see what the behavior is.